# Get full r_basicprofile information from LinkedIn API V2 using zoonman/linkedin-api-php-client

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am using this PHP SDK to connect to the LinkedIn API:

https://github.com/zoonman/linkedin-api-php-client

I am authenticating like so:

```
    // define client
    $client = new Client(
        $_ENV["YOUR_LINKEDIN_APP_CLIENT_ID"],
        $_ENV["YOUR_LINKEDIN_APP_CLIENT_SECRET"]
    );
    $client->setRedirectUrl($_ENV["YOUR_LINKEDIN_APP_REDIRECT"]);
    $client->setApiRoot('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/');

    // define scope
    $scopes = ['r_liteprofile','r_basicprofile','r_emailaddress'];

    // redirect to LinkedIn
    $loginUrl = $client->getLoginUrl($scopes);
    return(redirect($loginUrl));
```

Once authenticated I am requesting the "me" endpoint like so:

```
   if (isset($_GET['code'])):
        $client = new Client(
            $_ENV["YOUR_LINKEDIN_APP_CLIENT_ID"],
            $_ENV["YOUR_LINKEDIN_APP_CLIENT_SECRET"]
        );
        $client->setRedirectUrl($_ENV["YOUR_LINKEDIN_APP_REDIRECT"]);
        $client->setApiRoot('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/');

        // get access token and store in session
        $accessToken = $client->getAccessToken($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION["accessToken"]=$accessToken;
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

        // get user profile
        $profile = $client->get('me');
        print '<pre>';
        print_r($profile);
        print '</pre>';
    endif;
```

My response only includes the following:

```
    Array
(
    [lastName] => Array
        (
            [localized] => Array
                (
                    [en_US] => Blow
                )

            [preferredLocale] => Array
                (
                    [country] => US
                    [language] => en
                )

        )

    [firstName] => Array
        (
            [localized] => Array
                (
                    [en_US] => Joe
                )

            [preferredLocale] => Array
                (
                    [country] => US
                    [language] => en
                )

        )

    [profilePicture] => Array
        (
            [displayImage] => urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:12345678
        )

    [id] => 1234567
)
```

I am not getting all the data I have permission to request:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile

What am I doing wrong?

How do I get access to all these other fields?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use API v2 fields and methods. Try this:

```
$client->get('me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture,headline)');
```

In order to access some fields, you may need to ask for more permissions. Check out this links for more info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api#field-selections
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile#profile-fields-available-with-linkedin-partner-programs